# is the marriage valid?

Tags: nikah, love

if a man and a women commit a zina act together by doing a sexual act for e.g. the girl performing oral sex and the man touching her breast but they both did not have sex with eachother before marriage and afterwards they get their nikkah done they ask Allah forgiveness after they got their nikkah done a couple days later from committing the sin/haraam act before marriage do they have to do their nikkah again? please help as I am in desperate need for an answer and I wanted to know if the marriage is valid or not with eachother.

I would like to know what the prophet s.a.w. said about this in reference and what Allah mentions about it too if you can please with hadith and quran quotations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware A nikah is valid only if it is conducted with:

Iejaab (proposal for nikah)

Qubool (acceptance of the nikah proposal)

The nikah should be performed in the presence of two witnesses (2 men or 1 man and 2 women who are muslims and are mature)

And guardians or parents from both parties should attend. Again this varies depending on what school of thought you go with. In Hanafi having an imam or a wali is not a requirement.

Source - https://seekersguidance.org/answers/hanafi-fiqh/minimum-steps-must-taken-marriage-valid/

Comment: jazakallah khair for the source you linked brother, i also wanted to ask, the person who did the nikkah for the man and women (who is not a imam or wali) can he only be the witness or do you actually have to have 2 witnesses because someone that i know got their nikkah done and they only had the bride, groom, and the person who did their nikkah and said he is the witness, is that also allowed and could it be done that way because in that source i cannot find the mention about it.

Comment: Sorry I can’t be much help sister as My knowledge on this topic is very limited. I did try looking online to find something similar in response to your question but it all became a bit confusing and I’d rather not spread information that may be false or misleading.

Comment: alright jazakallah khair brother for the help

Comment: No problem sister.

Answer (score 0):

Allah Forgiver
Important to know the terms of right nikah

One of it :

The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: The marriage of a woman who marries without the consent of her guardians is void. (He said these words) three times. If there is cohabitation, she gets her dower for the intercourse her husband has had. If there is a dispute, the sultan (man in authority) is the guardian of one who has none.

Comment: jazakallah khair for the answer brother so even if the bride and groom got married for without the consent of the guardian it will still be void? brother also do you mind explaining what you mean by this part please when you mention this "If there is cohabitation, she gets her dower for the intercourse her husband has had. If there is a dispute, the sultan (man in authority) is the guardian of one who has none."

Comment: i wanted to know in this type of situation someone that i know got their nikkah done with only bride, groom and the person who did the nikkah said he is the witness their was no other witness except him so im not sure if that is accepted and secondly the girl got her nikkah done because she married a muslim man who is black and the bride is a muslim but she is Asian, her parents do not not accept him because of that so, in that type of situation is it still accepted marriage for halal way or is that haraam?

Comment: eventually in future the bride will tell her parents that she is married but for now she knows it isnt the right time.